# How can I copy an xml file into a folder and hide it?

Tags: c#

With this code I can copy an xml file from the internet and save it in a folder.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml", "test.xml");
```

The code works fine, but I need the test.xml file (file copied into the folder) to be hidden, so that it is visible only if I turn on "show hidden file and folders".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the file attributes, use `File.SetAttributes` for this. Though I also use `File.GetAttributes` first so that any existing attributes will be preserved.

```
string filename = "test.xml";
FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(filename);

attr |= FileAttributes.Hidden;

File.SetAttributes(filename,attr);
```

MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx

Comment: +1, especially for showing that you should read existing attributes first and then set the new one before setting them.

Comment: Yeh easy to overlook that one.

Answer (score 2):

File.SetAttributes("pathToFile",FileAttributes.Hidden)

Comment: You should first read the existing file attributes, add in `FileAttributes.Hidden`, and then write the new attributes. This preserves other things like the archive attribute properly.